# Decrypting encrypted 7zip archieve file using 7zip command-line utility

Tags: command-line, 7zip

I have a text file `myfile.txt` which I encrypt using [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) GUI Tool. So that it generates an encrypted archive `myfile.7z`

[image: settings in gui]

Now, my question is, how can I decrypt this file using 7za.exe command line tool and not the GUI tool. I need to add this functionality in my code to be able to decrypt files using 7zip command line exe, **please tell me what is the command to decrypt this `myfile.7z` encrypted archive using 7zip command line tool?**

Comment: Don't add the answer as an edit, [add it as an answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)!

Comment: thanks @Lattyware, i will update now

Answer (score 3):

well finally i figured it out. Using something like this would work:

[image]